# How to format a regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this string : 4.5 von 5 Sternen.

My desired output : 4.5/5

What I tried  `entry.rating.replace(/[a-z A-Z]/g , '/');` Which resulted in `4.5/5/` I dont need that extra slash just the one in the middle dividing the two numbers. I would love some help right now . Thanks in advance.

Comment: So that means you use `/[a-z A-Z]+/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `match + join` here:

```js
var s = '4.5 von 5 Sternen.';
var arr = s.match(/\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
var out = null;

if (arr != null)
  out = arr.join('/');

console.log(out);
//=> 4.5/5
```

- We are using regex `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?` in `.match` to match a number that may be integer or floating point number.
- Once we have array generated from `match` we use `join('/')` to get desired output.

Comment: You might want to implement some error checking in case of no match. `String#match` will return `null` if no match is found.